# PHP create two unordered lists from array

Tags: php, html-lists

I'm trying to create two unordered lists from a PHP array, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573717/php-count-items-in-array-split-total-by-two-create-two-ul-lists-with-equal-nu) which is pretty much what I'm looking for, but I would like the first list to have 11 items, the second list to have the rest. Here's my code:

```
<?php if ($rows) : 

    $items = count($rows);
    $split = ceil($items/2);
    $firsthalf = array_slice($rows,$split);
    $secondhalf = array_slice($rows,0,$split);
?>

    <div class="tickets">

      <div class="col1">
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($firsthalf as $item) : ?>
          <li><a href="">test 1</a></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col2">
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($secondhalf as $item) : ?>
          <li><a href="">test 2</a></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: Just `shuffle` the array before you do your `array_slice`ing.

Comment: how to make the first list have 11 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to split the array into 11 items and then the rest [using array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$firsthalf = array_slice($rows, 0, 11);
$secondhalf = array_slice($rows, 11);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) documentation, you can see that you specify the size of the split as the third parameter, while the second is the offset:

```
<?php 
    if ($rows) : 
      $firsthalf = array_slice($rows, 0, 11); // returns 11 rows from the start
      $secondhalf = array_slice($rows, 11); // returns everything after the 11th row
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much (same answer as below) - but thanks for the documentation to go with :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// $items = count($rows);
// $split = ceil($items/2);
$firsthalf = array_slice($rows, 0, 11);
$secondhalf = array_slice($rows, 11);
```